# MYSql calculate total amount from sub query using HQL

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate

```
@Query(value = "SELECT SUM(amount) FROM (SELECT t1.amount FROM Table1 t1 " 
            + "INNER JOIN t1.table2 t2 "
            + "GROUP BY t1.txnId) a ")
    public double getAmount();
```

Above HQL is not working.. Showing  below exception

> unexpected token: ( near line 1, column 25

Answer (score 0):

HQL subqueries can occur only in the select or where clauses.

E.g valid queries:

```
select cat.id, (select max(kit.weight) from cat.kitten kit) from Cat as cat
```

or

```
select c from DomesticCat as cat 
where cat.name not in (
   select name.nickName from Name as name )
```

Source: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-subqueries

I would suggest to use native query instead HQL.